# Problem with loading JSON data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm currently working on a simple web page where I have to use some data from a JSON file, with Javascript.
I have the following code :

```
var rItems

// Load JSON data
async function loadJSON() {
    let response = await fetch("./javascript/recycling.json")
    rItems = await response.json()

    console.log(rItems) // Works fine, I get the expected data
}

loadJSON()


function test() {
    console.log(rItems) // -> 'undefined'
}

test()
```

The problem is that my rItems variable is not initializing correctly. I can use it inside of loadJSON function, but as soon as I try to use this variable outside of it ( so in the test() function ), it is undefined.

I'm guessing that it's due to my loadJSON function being asynchronous. The test function is executed even though the data is not loaded yet. How can I fix that?

My guess would be initializing rItems each time I call any function, so for example I would do this:

```
async function loadJSON() {
    let response = await fetch("./javascript/recycling.json")
    return await response.json()
}

async function test() {
    let rItems = await loadJSON();
    console.log(rItems) // -> 'undefined'
}
```

But I don't think it is a good idea because first it makes me load the data each time I call my function ( which will be called many times ), and second it makes me once again deal with asynchronous functions...

Thanks for any help!

I tried loading my JSON data each time I execute a function, but I don't think is it the best idea